# How do I join three tables from two different databases(ms.access and mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, pdo

I want to join three tables from two different databases(ms.access and mysql) but i have error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\job\system\hrd\view_absensi.php on line 69

This is my code

```
<?php include"koneksi.php"; 
 $sql=$dbsql+$dbaccess->query(" attach database dbsql.db as db1
                                attach database dbaccess.db as db2
                                SELECT * p.nip,p.nama,abs.Date_Time
                                FROM 
                                   $db1.HR_Personnel as pabs
                                JOIN $db1.TA_Record_Info AS abs ON abs.Per_ID = pabs.ID
                                JOIN $db2.pegawai_tetap AS p ON p.nip = pabs.Per_Code"); 
        while($p=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

and this koneksi.php

```
    <?php
try{
$dbsql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbpenggajian', $user='root', $pass='');
    }
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
try{
    $dbaccess = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=D:\\Kepegawaian Arto Moro\BACK_UP_ABSENSI\TJ_Main_Data.mdb; Uid=userName;Pwd=everyday;");
    }
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

how to solve this problem? thanks for the advice

Comment: You can't, you'll have to work around it with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to join three tables from two different databases.

Import your Access database into mysql first.

Comment: I do "join three tables from two different databases" because because the fingerprint system on the database update Ms.Access and I want shyncronize with a web-based personnel information system.whether to export Ms.Access be automatically synchronized with mysql?